# Write pyspark sql query output to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, export-to-csv

My code to execute an sql query, convert it to pandas and then write to a csv file is per below but see errors when executing it.

> src_query = """select * from table"""

> df = spark.sql(src_query).toPandas()

> df.write.csv('output.csv', index=False)

This is the error I see at the last line when executing it - "invalid syntax"
Can anyone share any tips on how I can easily write the spark output to csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `pyspark`'s syntax.

```
df.write.csv
```

However, you converted the dataframe into `Pandas` dataframe with this.

```
df = spark.sql(src_query).toPandas()
```

Thus, `df` is the pandas object and you need to use pandas syntax.

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I still get invalid syntax error. Not sure what could be wrong in what seems as straightforward as this.

Comment: Do you know where you are getting the error message?

Comment: df = spark.sql(src_query).toPandas() - This is the line where the error is

Comment: Could you add a code where you initialize `spark` and how you are running the spark?  (ie: on databricks? spark-submit?)

Comment: Thanks, I think I didnt realize what I was doing. The code works fine now after I converted the spark dataframe to pandas and using to_csv method.

Answer (score 1):

try this and see

```
filename='output.csv'
df.to_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: That gave me the same error for filename.